# Is $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[-\pi, \pi]$.? yes/NO

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [-\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous $2\pi$-periodic function whose Fourier series is given by$$\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_k \cos kt + b_k \sin kt)$$
Let, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$f_n(t) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k \cos kt + b_k \sin kt)$$
and let $f_0$ denote the constant function $\frac{a_0}{2}$.

Is $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[-\pi, \pi]$.?

## My attempt : my answer  is yes

i was thinking about Weierstrass' M-test
$
\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}} |\frac{a_0}{2}+a_k \cos(kt) + b_k \sin(kt)| \leq \frac{1}{2} +|a_n| + |b_n| =: M_n
$

by $M_n $ test   it will  uniformly convergence  on $[-\pi,\pi]$

is  my answer is correct or not ? Pliz help me

Comment: Without any further information about $a_n$ and $b_n$, you can't even conclude that the series converges, let alone uniformly. In your argument, how do you know that $\sum M_n$ converges, as required for Weierstrass's M-test to apply?

Comment: @Bungo..let me thinks mores